# Retrieving a list of objects with null in the properties after applying resultTransformer

Tags: hibernate

In a criteria query I am getting a list of results in a right way.

As I dont want to all the fields from the entities projection is introduced to specify these fields. Ok, with projection is working fine but, instead of a List of entity is getting a list of object.

As I read, I need to apply `setResultTransformer(ClassName.class)`. When resultTransformer is applied, a list of className are retrieved but all the atributes of the object are NULL. I have tried different parameters to the resultTransformer and always getting a list of object with null in all attributes.

Eg.:

```
criteria.setProjection(proList)
   .setResultTransformer( 
       new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(TramiteTrafico.class));
```

If not resultTransformer is applied getting values are right.
Any idea why?

Thanks all!!

Comment: show the query,  you need to use aliases in the select clause so that the field names fetched match the property name (getter/setter) of you class into which the values need to be copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the property name of the class match the alias used in the projection list.

Something like list

```
class CatVO {
  String getCatName()  { ..}
  void setCatName(String catName) {..}
  String getKitName()  { ..}
  void setKitName(String kitName) {..}
}


List results = session.createCriteria(Domestic.class, "cat")
    .createAlias("kittens", "kit")
    .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
        .add( Projections.property("cat.name"), "catName" )
        .add( Projections.property("kit.name"), "kitName" )
    ).setResultTransformer( 
       new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(CatVO.class))
     .list();
```

Comment: Exactly!! That was the problem. I am getting other with relationated entities. I am going deep with the other problem.

Thanks all!!